# C# Launch Steam Game with server infos

Tags: c#, server, steam

Currently I am working on a program that should launch a steam game and connect it to a server. My code:

```
Process.Start("steam://rungameid/346110", "138.201.77.6:27015");
```

It launches the game, but it does not connect to the server. I have also tried this:

```
Process.Start("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\steam\\steamapps\\common\\ARK\\ShooterGame\\Binaries\\Win64\\ShooterGame.exe", "+connect:138.201.77.6:27015");
```

It also launches the game and tries to connect. The info pops up that the game is trying to connect, but it crashes.

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Thx for the help.